# How to combine two images into one so I can vertically align across all browsers?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I'm creating an e-commerce site and I'm having trouble vertically centering all my thumbnails. The problem is all my images are different sizes and getting each one to vertical align across all browsers is turning out to be a pain. I've looked into the different CSS options, `display-table`, `line-height`, and others. They worked in modern browsers, but not well in IE (of course). My thought is the large big time sites are resizing the image (which I can do with no problem) and then overlaying the image on top of a background the exact size they need. Does anyone know if this is how it's done? IF so can you direct me to some documentation of how to do this in PHP?

Or if someone thinks I can do this without all the extra work of overlaying images please let me know. In-case you want to see what I'm working with here ya go:

**HTML**

```
<a href="#">
    <div id="product">
        <div id="product-image">
            <img src="" border="0" />
        </div>
        <div id="product-name"></div>
        <div id="product-price"></div>
    </div>
</a>
```

**OPTION 1 : JQUERY** (this seemed to be my best hope, but couldn't get it to work right)

```
var h = $('#product-image').height();
$.map($('#product-image img'), function(e)
{
    var top =( h- $(e).height())/2;
    $(e).css("margin-top",top);
});
```

**OPTION 2 : CSS**

```
#product
{
    float:left;
    margin:5px;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid #999;
}
#product-image
{
    margin:2px auto;
    width:194px;
    height:145px;
    text-align:center;
}
#product-image img
{
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

**EDIT**

I found the working code, thanks Explosion Pills. For anyone trying to get this work I would suggest using this jQuery method and Fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/9VfUS/1/:

**WORKING JQUERY**

```
var h = $('div#product-image').height();
$('div#product-image img').each(function ()
{
    var top = (h - $(this).height()) / 2;
    $(this).css("margin-top",top);
});​
```

Comment: show us an example of how you want it to look, not how it shouldn't look

Comment: I made a Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9VfUS/ and Explosion Pills method is working well in modern browsers, but when I try IE in compatibility mode it aligns all the images to the top. Maybe IE compatibility mode isn't the best way to test this, but I figure if it works in that it will work for almost everyone.

Comment: Derek, good idea. I'll fix it.

Comment: not need JavaScript use line height 145px :)

Comment: @ Tarun, I've played with `line-height` and I couldn't get to work correct with all the different sized images. Maybe I did it wrong, could you show and example? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use JavaScript, I would do it that way as it's surefire to get things to work the way you want.  You are using `.map` for the wrong purpose.  You want `.each`:

```
$('#product-image img').each(function () {
   var top = (h - $(this).height()) / 2;
   $(this).css("margin-top",top);
});
```

I assume that `h` was already calculated correctly as the tallest image or the height of the container or what have you.  If it's not, then you have to do that.

Comment: Hey Explosion, I guess knowing what `h` does might help, lol. `var h = $('#product-image').height();`. I tried your code and it centers the top of all the images to the middle. Look in my post and I'll show what it's doing. BTW, I agree that jquery would be the best option for browser compatability ;)

Comment: @Mike if you don't want to center the top of all images to the middle, where do you want to center them exactly?

Comment: I changed `$('#product-image img')` to `$('div#product-image img')` and it works just fine now. Not sure why that made a difference but I tried many times. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if you know in advance the sizes of your images...

```
HTML:
<a href="#">
    <div class="product">
        <div class="product-image" data-image-loc="path_to_your_image">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="product-name"></div>
        <div class="product-price"></div>
    </div>
</a>

CSS:
div.product-image {
    background-position:center center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-attachment: scroll;
}
div.product-image-width-x-height {
    width:{width}px;
    height:{height}px;
}

JS:
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.product-image').each(function() {
        $(this).css({backgroundImage:url($(this).attr('data-image-loc'))});
    });
});
```

If you don't know your sizes, then a resize script that serves all your images to a new size would fix that, and you would simply move the width/height css properties to the div#product-image CSS declaration.

Comment: Hey Derek, I'm working with PHP and MySQL to bring up the images dynamically. I will be having thousands of images all with different names. This seems like I would have to change the `path_to_your_image` with every image served, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, but you could do that onDomReady in javascript. I'll edit my example.

Comment: I like this approach! Maybe it;s my lack of skills, but how would I pass the image path, height, and width to javascript from php? I've been looking and I can't find any good documentation on how to do that. Thanks

Comment: Depends on your system... I use CakePHP, so using that example, in your action just set variables for image, height, width using $this->set();, ie: $this->set('image', $image_location_determined_in_php);

Then in your view you'd have the $image variable which you can echo wherever you need to using <?php echo $image; ?>